# pug template not including stylesheets

Tags: css, express, pug

I have a .pug template in my express project that isn't including its stylesheets. I've checked out the documentation for pug but its been no use :( I'm not sure what to do

FILE TREE:

```
views
`-- index.pug
`-- css
    `-- styles.css
```

I'm trying to include 3 stylesheets: styles.css (personal stylesheet), a bootstrap CDN (I have installed bootstrap in my project already), and a google fonts stylesheet

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title Cloudii Weather Analysis
    style
      // BOOTSTRAP link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      integrity='sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u' crossorigin='anonymous')

     //GOOGLE FONTS link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap')

     // STYLES.CSS link(rel='stylesheet', href='./css/styles.css')

  body
    img(src='images/cloudii_bg.png')

    div
      h2 cloudii
      img(src='images/cloudii_logo.png')

    div.form-row
      div.form-group.col-md-6
        label.label city
        input#inputCity.form-control

      div.form-group.col-md-4
        label.label state
        select(id="inputState" class="form-control")
          each state in states
            option(value=state.id) #{state.name}


      div(class="form-group col-md-2")
        label.label zip
        input(type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip")
        button(id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block hoverable">check weather)
```

Comment: Do you expect here that `pug` will include the content of a css file within it's rendered output ? Also the `link` tag should not be inside a `style` tag

Answer (score 0):

I had to point express.static to the views folder then place the stylesheet inside the views folder and it works!